# Good resources on using a QT backend with a C# Gui

Tags: c#, .net, c++, wpf, qt

I am interested in creating a WPF user interface for a QT project. I am wondering if anyone has any recommendations for articles / books which might cover this or similar topics.

I am aware that I would need to wrap the QT dll but am unsure of the logistics of this.

Cheers

Mike.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/activeqt-dotnet.html
- http://developer.qt.nokia.com/faq/answer/is_qt_compatible_with_.net
- http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/activeqt.html